# filter does not work with ng-option derived from an array but works well with static option

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="myOption" class= "form-control" ng-options="value.status for value in records | unique:'status'"> </select>
```

shows 1 record when run for the below filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in records | filter:myOption">
            <td>{{data.vehicle_no}}</td>
            <td>{{data.vehicle_type}}</td>
            <td>{{data.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

but when i change the option to use static options e.g

```
<select ng-model="myOption" class= "form-control">
<option>free</option>
<option>busy</option></select>
```

it returns two records for me (which is correct)

Please advise how can I make these filter works well with ng-options. I am kind of stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to filter with the ng-model value declared on your select tab, you have to define a data source in the ng-options directive.
In your code you dont specify the value of your options, you should use a syntaxe like this

```
ng-options="value.status as value.status for value in records..."
```

the first `value.status` defines the value of each options in the generated select.

here is a working example, hope it will help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/p7mqAIQlh7QIgYlSYMwK?p=preview